# How to set a cap and a floor to predictions with Neural Prophet (new version of Prophet)

Tags: python, neural-network, time-series, forecasting, facebook-prophet

Using NeuralProphet package for financial forecasting, I'm trying to set a minimum value (floor) and a maximum value (cap) for my predictions, for example not to forecast negative values nor too large values.

I found this document about saturating forecasts in Prophet :
https://facebook.github.io/prophet/docs/saturating_forecasts.html#forecasting-growth
But this method does not work with NeuralProphet. The logistic function for growth is not available and I get the following error when I create the ['cap'] and ['floor'] columns in my dataset :
ValueError: Unexpected column {name} in data
I can't find any information in the documentation of NeuralProphet.
Any idea of a proper way to do it ?
Thank you!